# Rebuild index --> update statistics?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, maintenance

If I run Rebuild Index Task in maintenance plan, do I have to update statistics using Update Statistcs Task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes

Column statistics are not rebuilt, only index statistics

```
--random data
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo (bar int PRIMARY KEY, humbug char(2000))
INSERT dbo.foo (bar, humbug) VALUES (1, 'aaa')
INSERT dbo.foo (bar, humbug) VALUES (2, 'bbb')
INSERT dbo.foo (bar, humbug) VALUES (3, 'ccc')
INSERT dbo.foo (bar, humbug) VALUES (4, 'aaa')
INSERT dbo.foo (bar, humbug) VALUES (5, 'bbb')
INSERT dbo.foo (bar, humbug) VALUES (6, 'ccc')
INSERT dbo.foo (bar, humbug) VALUES (7, 'ccc')
INSERT dbo.foo (bar, humbug) VALUES (8, 'ccc')
INSERT dbo.foo (bar, humbug) VALUES (9, 'ccc')
INSERT dbo.foo (bar, humbug) VALUES (10, 'cc')

INSERT dbo.foo SELECT bar+10, humbug FROM dbo.foo

--generate index stats + column stats
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = 12
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE humbug = 'bbb'

--created date
SELECT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([id]) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME([id]),
    NAME,
    STATS_DATE ([id], indid)
FROM
    dbo.sysindexes
WHERE
    OBJECT_NAME([id]) = 'foo'
ORDER BY
    STATS_DATE ([id], indid)  DESC

--Relax, have a coffee

--rebuild
ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.foo REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90)

--check again
SELECT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([id]) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME([id]),
    NAME,
    STATS_DATE ([id], indid)
FROM
    dbo.sysindexes
WHERE
    OBJECT_NAME([id]) = 'foo'
ORDER BY
    STATS_DATE ([id], indid)  DESC

--only index stats were updated
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Rebuilding the indexes will generate new statistics "for free".

Comment: So it does all existing statistics (column and index)?

Comment: Rebuilding an index, for example by using ALTER INDEX … REBUILD, will also update index statistics with the equivalent of using WITH FULLSCAN. Rebuilding indexes does not update column statistic (see http://sqlblog.com/blogs/ben_nevarez/archive/2009/10/06/rebuilding-indexes-vs-updating-statistics.aspx for details)